# Performance hit while Comparing Rows in absence of key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

May anyone please help me on this.

Database: SQL Server 2008, table with 18 million rows.

I have two tables and I need to check missing rows between two tables, as I don't have any key column.

I concatenated all the column and called it as oldrow and newrow

But my problem is this query tooks me more than 6 hours and still executing even after indexing done.

Can anyone please suggest me some other solution using BINARY_CHECKSUM or HASHBYTES

Query I tried:

```
SELECT  ,
OLD.Resistor ,
OLD.ResistorID ,
OLD.Capacitor ,
OLD.CapacitorID ,
OLD.Years 
,CASE WHEN New.NewRow IS NULL THEN 'Record Deleted' ELSE 'No Change' END AS     
FixMessage
FROM #oldfinal Old
LEFT OUTER JOIN #newfinal New ON Old.OldRow = New.NewRow
UNION

SELECT  ,
NEW.Resistor ,
NEW.ResistorID ,
NEW.Capacitor ,
NEW.CapacitorID ,
NEW.Years ,
'Record Added' AS FixMessage
FROM #newfinal New
LEFT OUTER JOIN #oldfinal Old ON New.NewRow = Old.OldRow
WHERE Old.OldRow IS NULL
```

Please please help me. Even I tried except logic, but unfortunately no much difference

Comment: Add a primary key and then you can compare those rows easily and efficiently ....

Comment: Can you add table metadata (incl. indexes) to your question?

Comment: @marc_s: i don't have any column which is not have any duplicate. lots of duplicate present in the table..

Comment: Add a non-unique index

Comment: @MilanTomeš: i have added clustered index on resistorid column, but no luck...

Comment: You need an index on #oldfinal.OldRow and another one on #newfinal.NewRow

Comment: @MilanTomeš: Do i need to create cluster or noncluster index please suggest

Comment: When i tried to create non cluster index on oldrow and new row i am getting error "Column 'oldrow' in table '#oldfinal' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102970/discussion-between-rajee-kasthuri-and-milan-tomes).

Comment: What's your SQL Server version? Does it support EXCEPT/INTERSECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the following script:

- It creates a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on both `#oldfinal` and `#newfinal` to speed up joins
- It uses a `FULL JOIN` rather than the `UNION` of two `LEFT JOIN` statements, fewer statements should speed up the query

I took some guesses as to the types of the columns, modify as appropriate.

Note that I think this doesn't make much sense if rows are not unique for `oldrow` and `newrow`. Perhaps you should filter out duplicates id's first?

---

```
CREATE TABLE #oldfinal(oldrow INT,resistor VARCHAR(256),resistorID INT,capacitor VARCHAR(256),capacitorID INT,years INT);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX oldfinal_oldrow ON #oldfinal(oldrow);
CREATE TABLE #newfinal(newrow INT,resistor VARCHAR(256),resistorID INT,capacitor VARCHAR(256),capacitorID INT,years INT);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX newfinal_oldrow ON #newfinal(newrow);

SELECT
    ISNULL(o.resistor,n.resistor) AS resistor,
    ISNULL(o.resistorid,n.resistorid) AS resistorid,
    ISNULL(o.capacitor,n.capacitor) AS capacitor,
    ISNULL(o.capacitorid,n.capacitorid) AS capacitorid,
    ISNULL(o.years,n.years) AS years,
    CASE 
        WHEN n.newrow IS NOT NULL AND o.oldrow IS NOT NULL THEN 'No Change'
        WHEN n.newrow IS NOT NULL THEN 'Record Added' -- n.newrow IS NOT NULL AND o.oldrow IS NULL 
        ELSE 'Record Deleted'                         -- n.newrow IS NULL AND o.oldrow IS NOT NULL 
    END AS fixmessage
FROM
    #oldfinal AS o 
    FULL JOIN #newfinal AS n ON 
        n.newrow=o.oldrow;

DROP TABLE #newfinal;
DROP TABLE #oldfinal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to show the matching rows? It's a task for set operations, so why don't you simply use `EXCEPT`?

To get the rows missing in tableB:

```
select * 
from tableA

except 

select *
from tableB
```

No need to concat and dealing with NULLs...

Comment: From the question: *"Even I tried except logic, but unfortunately no much difference"*. His problem is with his query being slow.